# When i use Assert.assertFalse(), to check the absence of an element, my scripts are getting failed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

```
Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("element's xpath")).isDisplayed(),
            "Bug!! The element is appeared");
```

When i run my code with the above script, my scripts are failing with the statement like "can't find the element, (Which is mentioned int he element's xpath)" 
Now what i have to do? My notion is to verify the element is not present in the screen

Comment: Are you sure, the element's xpath is correct ?

Comment: even i have that doubt, but i checked it and it was the exact xpath for the tooltip element, which will be displayed as a notification for 5 seconds

Comment: Use WebDriverWait with visibilityOf, it'll wait for element to be visible and will fail the test if not found. http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Comment: As Erki sugested you can use the following code to wait for the element. `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 240);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your xpath goes here")));`

And then you can perform the assertion.

Comment: Also note it depends on your definition of "not displayed". I can assume that perhaps when this notification disappears, it is removed from the DOM - thus the `.findElement` call will throw an exception because it *really* can't find it. The `.isDisplayed` call will only be called if the element is inside the DOM, which it sounds like it isn't.

Comment: Mr.Arran, whatever you mentioned is the command is that exactly what happens to me., so now what i have to do? the element is not in DOM itself

Comment: Lucan, try this code----try{ write code to findElement; System.out.println("FAIL-element is present")}catch(NoSuchElementException e){System.out.println("PASS - element not present");   You could see some syntax errors.....!!

Comment: Syntax errors in the code which i gave.....

Answer (score 0):

findElement throws an exception if no matching element is found, so you tests will fail with the selenium exception, not JUnit.

you can use **findElements** (which doesn't throws exceptions) and check that the returned list length is equals to 0

See details in the [Selenium documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29)

Answer (score 0):

I see that this has been asked a long while ago, but perhaps someone who is looking for a solution to the similar problem will find it useful now. 
I have a certain way to deal with such problems, not sure if it's a good way to do this, but at least it makes sense and does the job.

**Firstly, I usually define a separate method for finding such elements:**

```
private static WebElement element = null; 

public static WebElement findYourElement(WebDriver driver) {
    try {
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath_here"));
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        element = null;
        return element;
    }
    return element;
}
```

You can see here that the possible NoSuchElementException is being caught should it be thrown. In case of exception, the value for "element" is also set to null, since in my program there might be values from previous elements stored here and we don't to have any other non-relevant elements here.

**Next comes the assertion:**

```
Assert.assertFalse(findYourElement != null, "Bug!! The element is there!"
```

Here the assertFalse method fails if the element returned by the findYourElement is not empty, yielding a True result from element != null comparison and making assertFalse fail, as it is expecting to have a false value in order to continue. 
You could just as well go:

```
Assert.assertTrue(findYourElement = null, "Bug!! The element is there!"
```

I think that such solution helps to keep things well organized, but on the other hand it may be larger in terms of code volume and more complicated too. It also depends how good are you with Java and if you are willing to mess with the exceptions. 
I am no Java guru myself, so any contribution towards improving my current solution will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do this small change, it definitely works

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.xpath("element's xpath")).size()<1;,
        "Bug!! The element is appeared");
```